# How should I validate a user's credentials against an ADAM instance over SSL?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Apologies in advance as I haven't had much experience with directories before.

I have an ASP.net application, and I have to validate its users against an Active Directory Application Mode instance running on Server 2k3. I was previously attempting a connection with DirectoryEntry and catching the COMException if the user's credentials (userPrincipalName & password) were wrong, but I had a number of problems when trying to bind as users who weren't a member of any ADAM groups (which is a requirement).

I recently found the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) library, which seems a lot more promising, but although it works on my local machine, I'm having some troubles when testing this in our testbed environment. Chances are I'm simply misunderstanding how to use these objects correctly, as I wasn't able to find any great documentation on the matter. Currently I am creating a PrincipalContext with a Windows username and password, then calling the AuthenticateCredentials with the *user's* userPrincipalName and password. Here's a very short exert of what I'm doing:

```
using (var serviceContext = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.ApplicationDirectory,
    serverAddress,
    rootContainer,
    ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer,
    serviceAccountUsername,
    serviceAccountPassword)) {
bool credentialsValid = serviceContext.ValidateCredentials(userID, password, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.SimpleBind)
}
```

If the user's credentials are valid, I then go on to perform other operations with that principal context. As I said, this works for both users with and without roles in my own environment, but not in our testbed environment. My old DirectoryEntry way of checking the user's credentials still works with the same configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very long morning, I was able to figure out the problem!

The exception message I was receiving when calling ValidateCredentials was extremely vague. After installing Visual Studio 2008 in the test environment (which is on the other side of the country, mind you!), I was able to debug and retrieve the HRESULT of the error. After some very deep searching in to Google, I found some very vague comments about "SSL Warnings" being picked up as other exceptions, and that enabling "SCHANNEL logging" (which I'm very unfamiliar with!) might reveal some more insight. So, after switching that on in the registry and retrying the connection, I was presented with this:

> The certificate received from the remote server does not contain the expected name. It is therefore not possible to determine whether we are connecting to the  correct server. The server name we were expecting is ADAMServer. The SSL connection request has  failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

I found this rather strange, as the *old* method of connecting via SSL worked fine. In any case, my co-worker was able to spot the problem - the name on the SSL certificate that had been issued on the server was that of the DNS name ("adam2.net") and not the host name ("adamserver"). Although I'm told that's the norm, it just wasn't resolving the correct name when using PrincipalContext.

Long story short; re-issuing a certificate with the computer name and not the DNS name fixed the problem!